# data table create row

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

I've looked extensively on stack overflow but wasn't able to find anything useful for my desired output.

To illustrate, consider the following example data frame:

```
      D     X     Y     Z     A     B     C    Total
 1   abc    2     3     4     7     2     1      19
```

The total corresponds to the sum of each row. For simplicity, let B=19, which is the total. The output I desire is:

```
    D     X     Y     Z     A     B     C    Total
 1  abc   1     2     3     4     5     2      B
 2  N/A   1/B   2/B   3/B   4/B   5/B   2/B    1
```

Here, each element in the 1st row is divided by the total number, and this is reflected in the 2nd row. To create a column for total, I used mutate and did this:

```
df <- df %>% mutate(Total = X + Y + Z + A + B + C)
```

But I wasn't able to figure out how to create a row where each element is divisible by the Total number.

Any help would be appreciated! I wouldn't mind using mutate or data.table in doing this, as I used data.table to create a big dataframe.

EDIT1: I'm really sorry for not mentioning this, but a column includes some strings. I have editted the above to reflect this.

Comment: Opps, i'm sorry! It is indeed 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a `dplyr` answer to your question.  What you actually want to do might be more complex, but this simple `bind_rows`, `filter`, and `mutate_all` works for the simple provided example.

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(x = 2:3, y = 3:4, z = letters[1:2], total = c(0, 19))
bind_rows(
    df,
    filter(df, row_number() == n()) %>%
        mutate_if(is.numeric, funs(. / total))
)

# x         y z total
# 1 2.0000000 3.0000000 a     0
# 2 3.0000000 4.0000000 b    19
# 3 0.1578947 0.2105263 b     1
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Like my above comment in the previous post(sorry for not mentioning this), but if a column included strings, this impacts mutate_all and I received this error: Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: non-numeric argument to binary operator.

Comment: @ynitSed no problem.  See the updated example in my solution above.  Basically, `mutate_if` should do the trick then to only operate on numerics.

Comment: This works. If I had multiple rows and just wanted to perform the calculation for the last row, would this change the code a lot?

Answer (score 1):

I have added one more row to make the solution more general.

In base R, we can divide the dataframe by the `Total` column in that row and then `rbind` it with original dataframe.

```
new_df <- rbind(df, df/df[, "Total"])
new_df

#           X         Y         Z         A         B          C Total
#1  2.0000000 3.0000000 4.0000000 7.0000000 2.0000000 1.00000000    19
#2  1.0000000 2.0000000 5.0000000 6.0000000 7.0000000 4.00000000    25
#11 0.1052632 0.1578947 0.2105263 0.3684211 0.1052632 0.05263158     1
#21 0.0400000 0.0800000 0.2000000 0.2400000 0.2800000 0.16000000     1
```

If the order is important and you want to maintain it, then we can just reorder it

```
rbind(new_df[c(T, F),], new_df[c(F, T),])

#           X         Y         Z         A         B          C Total
#1  2.0000000 3.0000000 4.0000000 7.0000000 2.0000000 1.00000000    19
#11 0.1052632 0.1578947 0.2105263 0.3684211 0.1052632 0.05263158     1
#2  1.0000000 2.0000000 5.0000000 6.0000000 7.0000000 4.00000000    25
#21 0.0400000 0.0800000 0.2000000 0.2400000 0.2800000 0.16000000     1
```

---

**EDIT**

If there are certain columns which are string we can ignore them and use `bind_rows` instead of `rbind` as it directly returns `NA` for non-matching columns.

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(df1, df1[!names(df1) %in% "D"]/df1[, "Total"])

#         X         Y         Z         A         B          C  Total    D
#1 2.0000000 3.0000000 4.0000000 7.0000000 2.0000000 1.00000000    19  abc
#2 1.0000000 2.0000000 5.0000000 6.0000000 7.0000000 4.00000000    25  def
#3 0.1052632 0.1578947 0.2105263 0.3684211 0.1052632 0.05263158     1 <NA>
#4 0.0400000 0.0800000 0.2000000 0.2400000 0.2800000 0.16000000     1 <NA>
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(X = c(2, 1), Y = c(3, 2), Z = c(4, 5), A = c(7, 
  6), B = c(2, 7), C = c(1, 4), Total = c(19, 25)), .Names = c("X", 
  "Y", "Z", "A", "B", "C", "Total"), row.names = c("1", "2"), class = "data.frame")

df1 <-structure(list(X = c(2, 1), Y = c(3, 2), Z = c(4, 5), A = c(7, 
6), B = c(2, 7), C = c(1, 4), Total = c(19, 25), D = c("abc", 
"def")), .Names = c("X", "Y", "Z", "A", "B", "C", "Total", "D"
 ), row.names = c("1", "2"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thanks for this Ronak! If a column included some strings, say within the list you also have say, D = c("a", "b") and obviously cant perform the calculation I want, how can I exclude this calculation out for this column?

Comment: @ynitSed You can remove the `D` column from calculation by doing `df[-columnnumber]` if you know the column number of D column or `df[!names(df) %in% "D"]`